# Search Dialogs in Epicor

Tags: customization, epicorerp

Hopefully someone here is familiar with creating customizations in Epicor 9.  I've posted this to the Epicor forums as well, but unfortunately that forum seems pretty dead.  Any help I can get would be much appreciated.

I've created a customization on the Order Entry form to display and store some extra information about our orders.  One such field is the architect on the job.  We store the architects in the customer table using a GroupCode of AR to distinguish them from regular customers.  I have successfully added a button that launches a customer search dialog and filters the results to only display the architects (those with GroupCode AR).  Here's where the problems come in.  I have two questions:

1:  On the customer search, there is a customer type field that defaults to a value of Customer.  Other choices are < all>, Suspect, or Prospect.  How can I make the search form default to < all>?

2:  How do I take the architect (customer) I select through the search dialog and populate its CustID into the ShortChar01 field on my Order Entry customization?  Here's the code I have:

```
private void SearchOnCustomerAdapterShowDialog()
{
    // Wizard Generated Search Method
    // You will need to call this method from another method in custom code
    // For example, [Form]_Load or [Button]_Click

    bool recSelected;
    //string whereClause = string.Empty;
    string whereClause = "GroupCode = 'AR'";
    System.Data.DataSet dsCustomerAdapter = Epicor.Mfg.UI.FormFunctions.SearchFunctions.listLookup(this.oTrans, "CustomerAdapter", out recSelected, true, whereClause);
    if (recSelected)
    {
        System.Data.DataRow adapterRow = dsCustomerAdapter.Tables[0].Rows[0];

        // Map Search Fields to Application Fields
        EpiDataView edvOrderHed = ((EpiDataView)(this.oTrans.EpiDataViews["OrderHed"]));
        System.Data.DataRow edvOrderHedRow = edvOrderHed.CurrentDataRow;
        if ((edvOrderHedRow != null))
        {
            edvOrderHedRow.BeginEdit();
            edvOrderHedRow["ShortChar01"] = adapterRow["CustID"];
            edvOrderHedRow.EndEdit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I select a record and click OK, I get an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are/were having is that you aren't adding the CustNum to the Sales Order first. In my mind I would do it this way first, but there is might be ChangeCustomer BO method in oTrans that you could call to make sure everything defaults correct.

```
EpiDataView edvOrderHed = ((EpiDataView)(this.oTrans.EpiDataViews["OrderHed"]));
if (edvOrderHed.HasRow)
    {

        edvOrderHed[edvOrderHed.Row].BeginEdit();
        edvOrderHed[edvOrderHed.Row]["CustNum"] = adapterRow["CustNum"];
        edvOrderHed[edvOrderHed.Row]["ShortChar01"] = adapterRow["CustID"];
        edvOrderHed[edvOrderHed.Row].EndEdit();
    }
```

Hope that is helpful, even if late.